# Eclipse Luna - Project is not showing up - Strange

Tags: java, eclipse, scope

I just installed Luna. I imported 3 projects all went well for a while.
Then I restarted eclipse and now it shows only two projects. I tried to import the missing project, but it says it already exists in the workspace.

I closed all other projects and pressed Ctrl+Shift+T to see if it still shows up the types from that invisible project. Yes, it shows files from that invisible project. I opened one of the files and selected Show In Project Explorer. Nothing happens.

Also, in the code when I press . after an String object, nothing shows up.

Seems to be strange. Any help?

Also, if I can do fresh import of all projects, that would help too. But again, I don't know why context assist is not working. I can try importing everything afresh. For this, what are all the eclipse related folders / files I need to remove?

**Edit**
[this](http://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/05/17/eclipse-working-sets-explained/) helped me with workingset / missing projects. But when I press . after an object, nothing comes up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For others benefit, it has to do with Working sets. You can click Down arrow in Project Explorer and select "Edit Active Working Set". In the window, on the left hand side, you can see your non-visible projects and move it to right hand side to make them show up under active working set. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the problem where Eclipse says it "already exists in the workspace":  I recently had a similar problem and I fixed it by unchecking the box that says "copy projects into workspace" and then hit refresh and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed this issue by clicking 'Deselect working set' ( under dropdown in project explorer ). For me, 'edit Active working set' was disabled to start with.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the projects exists on the file system in the workspace directory, but the actual project got deleted or never imported in the eclipse workspace. Take a look at the workspace directory, all three projects should be there. You can delete the "missing" project from the file system and reimport it again.

Comment: Nope. Thats not the case. Please check my own answer.